# Finding the height of the tree

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

Using SQL, I would like to follow the tree structure until last leaf. 
Tree = 1 and Knot = 2;Tree = 1 and Knot = 3;Tree = 1 and Knot = NULL (cumulative probability);Tree = 2 and Knot = 4; Tree = 2 and Knot = 5;Tree = 2 and Knot is null (cumulative probability); Tree = 3 and Knot = 6;Tree = 3 and Knot is null (cumulative probability);Tree = 4 and Knot is null (cumulative probability);  Tree = 5 and Knot is null (cumulative probability) ; Tree = 6 and Knot is null (cumulative probability) ;

Comment: Not sure, maybe [hierarchical queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm#SQLRF52315) can help you. If you provide your data organization example, table structure or something else, it will be easier to understand solution way.

Comment: What do you mean by "take probability"? What probability? How is it calculated?

Comment: In your example probability is just leaf value, so query in my answer calculates is fine, if build a real Tree of Probabilities, then each node should have probability too, answer of @MT0 shows that, if I understood his code right he supposed probability to go to each node is equal, and if no other conditions defined is right too.

Comment: "Probability is just a column in the table." What table? You have not shown a table. Please provide a [MCVE] with the DDL and DML statements for your table and your expected output.

Comment: The image does not explain the algorithm - Why is tree 4 not in the output? How is the library column generated? Why, given your table structure, can you not just do `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE probability IS NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

If you organize data like this you can do the following

```
with TREETAB as (
select '1' treenode, '2' nodeval from dual
union all
select '1' treenode, '3' nodeval from dual
union all
select '1' treenode, 'leaf1' nodeval from dual
union all
select '2' treenode, '4' nodeval from dual
union all
select '2' treenode, '5' nodeval from dual
union all
select '2' treenode, 'leaf2' nodeval from dual
union all
select '3' treenode, '4' nodeval from dual
union all
select '3' treenode, 'leaf3' nodeval from dual
union all
select '4' treenode, 'leaf4' nodeval from dual
union all
select '5' treenode, 'leaf5' nodeval from dual
union all
select '6' treenode, 'leaf6' nodeval from dual
)

select *
  from (SELECT t.*, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF Leaf,
                SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(nodeval, '/') "Path", level
           FROM TREETAB t
          start with t.treenode = 1
         CONNECT BY PRIOR t.nodeval = to_char(t.treenode))
 where Leaf = 1
 order by treenode;
```

If don't need detailed info about tree, leaf and a path, you can just check what there is no equal value `treenode` for `nodeval` like this

```
with TREETAB as
 (select '1' treenode, '2' nodeval
    from dual
  union all
  select '1' treenode, '3' nodeval
    from dual
  union all
  select '1' treenode, 'leaf1' nodeval
    from dual
  union all
  select '2' treenode, '4' nodeval
    from dual
  union all
  select '2' treenode, '5' nodeval
    from dual
  union all
  select '2' treenode, 'leaf2' nodeval
    from dual
  union all
  select '3' treenode, '4' nodeval
    from dual
  union all
  select '3' treenode, 'leaf3' nodeval
    from dual
  union all
  select '4' treenode, 'leaf4' nodeval
    from dual
  union all
  select '5' treenode, 'leaf5' nodeval
    from dual
  union all
  select '6' treenode, 'leaf6' nodeval from dual)

select *
  from TREETAB t
 where not exists
 (select t.treenode from TREETAB t2 where t2.treenode = t.nodeval)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you clear that is tree condition, the code above independent to tree length. Used data is just for sample.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the probabilities you are talking about are an equal probability for each branch then:

```
WITH data ( tree, knot ) AS (
  SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, NULL FROM DUAL 
),
probabilities ( tree, knot, probability ) AS (
  SELECT tree, knot, 1 / COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY tree ) FROM data
),
cumulative_probabilities ( tree, knot, probability, path ) AS (
  SELECT p.*, '/' || tree
  FROM   probabilities p
  WHERE  tree = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT p.tree, p.knot, p.probability * cp.probability, cp.path || '/' || p.tree
  FROM   probabilities p
         INNER JOIN
         cumulative_probabilities cp
         ON ( p.tree = cp.knot )
)
SELECT *
FROM   cumulative_Probabilities
WHERE  knot IS NULL;
```

**Output**:

```
TREE KNOT PROBABILITY PATH
---- ---- ----------- ------
   1      0.333333333 /1
   3      0.166666667 /1/3
   2      0.111111111 /1/2
   6      0.166666667 /1/3/6
   4      0.111111111 /1/2/4
   5      0.111111111 /1/2/5
```